# UISearchController ResultsController appearing over navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uistoryboard, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` which has it's own custom results controller, rather than filtering the contents in the immediate view.

The `UISearchBar` appears in the navigation bar correctly, but when I begin typing characters into the search box, my custom controller appears, and fills the entire screen, covering up the navigation bar and the window I'm typing my query into.

This used to work, but I recently changed my storyboard to have the `UINavigationController` as the entry point, leading into a `UITabBarController`, which then had it's tabbed controllers.

The `UITabBarController` now has all the logic for the searches, so it can route the actions taken on the search results to the appropriate tab via a protocol I've implemented.

Below is my storyboard, note, that the custom search result controller is the item sitting below the `UITabBarController`, and the unattached item on the top right corner, is used via a library and is attached to the top tab's controller internally.

I'm starting to wonder if this specific configuration works?  Can I have the `UINavigationController` in front of the `UITabBarController`?

I wanted to have a persistent search bar up top with all the shared search code in one spot (UITabBarController) rather than put a UINavigationController in front of each tab?

If this should work, are there any ideas why the custom search results controller is now covering the entire screen, instead of going under the navigation bar?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the issue was I needed to call

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

In the view controller that was already being displayed (tab 1)

When I moved the search code over to the `UITabBarController`, I moved that with it.

Comment: Been looking all day for this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to have

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Inside your SearchResultsControllers `ViewDidLoad()`

Should now be under the searchController searchBar.